# Multiplying and dividing variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, division, multiplication

I know this sounds simple and it's probably just something I am missing but here is what is happening. I have two variables that needed to be divided then multiplied by another variable. The two variables divided come out perfect but when I multiply that sum by the next variable it comes out horribly wrong (at least to me)

```
$horiFOV = 20;
$distObj = 35;

$sensorWidth = mysql_query("SELECT camlist.width FROM camlist WHERE camlist.camera = '$camSelect'");

$lensCalc = $distObj / $horiFOV;
$lensCalcA = $lensCalc * $sensorWidth;
```

I split them like this so I could echo the results of each. Also the mysql query results as 4.80
But the result of all this comes out to 12.25 where it should come out to something like 8.4.

Mind you this is all based off an excel spreadsheet that I am recreating on the web.

Comment: put some actual values and show the expected and observed results of the calculation - "horribly wrong" doesn't really help...

Comment: 1. Your code is invalid. That's not how you run a query and get the results. 2. Don't use mysql_* for new code. It's obsolete.

Comment: What is the output of your `$sensorWidth` variable? If you set it manually to 4.80, then everything works fine. The problem is your output. And heed John's words.

Comment: Then feel free to put how you should run a query because thats how ive been doing it and it works just fine. also I know mysql_ has been replaced with mysqli_ but I have not upgraded to php5 yet. Feel free to be constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your $sensorWidth = mysql_query() line with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT camlist.width FROM camlist WHERE camlist.camera = '$camSelect'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sensorWidth = $row['width'];
```

You can't perform math on a mysql result resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sensorWidth` value that's pulled from the Query may not be pulled correctly. Once it's pulled try adding the line:

```
$sensorWidth = floatVal($sensorWidth);
```

Before you try and do math with it.

This is assuming that the proper number is being pulled from the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT camlist.width FROM camlist WHERE camlist.camera = '$camSelect'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sensorWidth=floatval($row["width"]);//as mbsurfer suggested

$lensCalc = $distObj / $horiFOV;
$lensCalcA = $lensCalc * $sensorWidth;
```

And for future don't use `mysql_*` they are depreciated and no longer maintained and supported instead there are two alternative extensions: `pdo` and `mysqli` Details: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799,

Comment: I know mysqli_ has taken over but I haven't upgraded to php5 yet. will be doing so soon and will fix the code accordingly. Big thanks you and @Michael